# How to create a VictoryCursorContainer where a Scatter would appear on hover over the cursor line

Tags: victory-charts

I am trying to implement a Scatter point that follows the VictoryCursorContainer hover line (as seen in image).

Is setting the Scatter coordinates through updating a state in the `onCursorChange` handler the best way to achieve this ?

I tried doing a version of this here: https://codesandbox.io/s/scatter-victorycursorcontainer-forked-b1irbl

It seems like it's a bit laggy and the Scatter is rendered behind the line and the Cursor line.

Would appreciate any help / pointers here